# Scapy sr1 function without outputs

Tags: python, scapy

when I use the function sr1() on any packet i get the automatic output:
in send() function you can add extra parameter, #verbose=False# and it's stop printing outputs, but in sr1() i don't know how, and if it can even be done.

[the output after the sr1() function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyjLz.jpg)

thanks for any event

Comment: Please quote the output in your question instead of using a screenshot. Additionally, please provide the code you got so far...

Answer (score 3):

I believe the flag you want is "verbose=0".
Basic example:

```
sr1(packet, verbose=0)
```

Used in the 3-way handshake:

```
ip = IP(dst=target)  
syn = ip/TCP(sport=self.sport, dport=self.dport, flags="S", seq=self.seq)  
synack = sr1(syn, verbose=0, timeout=2)
```